# Decompose a linear functional into the difference of positive ones to apply Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Riesz–Markov–Kakutani (RMK) representation theorem relates a (not necessarily continuous) **positive** linear  map $\Lambda:\mathcal C_c (X) \to \mathbb C$ with a unique **non-negative** Radon measure on $X$. On the other hand, every finite signed Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ can be decomposed uniquely as $\mu = \mu^+ - \mu^-$ with $\mu^+,\mu^-$ being non-negative finite Borel measures.

Let $\Lambda:\mathcal C_c (X) \to \mathbb C$ be a linear map.

> Can we decompose $\Lambda$ into $\Lambda = \Lambda^+ - \Lambda^-$ with $\Lambda^+, \Lambda^-:\mathcal C_c (X) \to \mathbb C$ being positive?

If yes, we can apply RMK theorem to get $\mu^+$ representing $\Lambda^+$, and $\mu^-$ representing $\Lambda^-$. Then $\mu^+ - \mu^-$ will represent $\Lambda$.

---

**(Rudin)** Let

- $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space,
- $E:= \mathcal C_c (X)$ the complex vector space of all complex-valued continuous maps on $X$ with compact support, and
- $\Lambda:E \to \mathbb C$ (not necessarily continuous) positive linear. Here $\Lambda$ is **positive** means $f \in E \text{ s.t. } f(X) \subset \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ implies $\Lambda (f) \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$.

Then there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ on $X$ which contains all Borel sets of $X$, and there exists a unique non-negative measure $\mu$ on $\mathfrak{M}$ such that

1. $$\Lambda(f) = \int_X  f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in E.$$
2. $\mu(K) < \infty$ for every compact set $K \subseteq X$.
3. $\mu(E) = \inf \{\mu(V) \mid E \subset V, V \text{ open}\}$ for all $E \in \mathfrak{M}$.
4. $\mu(E) = \sup \{\mu(K) \mid K \subset E, K \text{ compact}\}$ for all open set $E \subseteq X$ and for all $E \in \mathfrak{M}$ with $\mu(E) <\infty$.
5. If $E \in \mathfrak{M}$ such that $A \subset E$, and $\mu(E)=0$, then $A \in \mathfrak{M}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, for in the case of a compact space $X$, an affirmative answer would imply that every linear functional on $C(X)$ is continuous, and this is clearly false (under the axiom of choice).

Comment: I don't get the reasoning behind "...would imply that every linear functional on $C(X)$ is continuous". Could you elaborate more?

Comment: A positive Radon measure on a compact space is necessarily finite (compact sets have finite measure), so the corresponding linear functional is continuous.

Comment: I got your idea. Is there any representation of a (not necessarily positive) linear functional by a (signed) measure?

Comment: Infinite signed measures are hard to define, let alone study!  How do you define $\sigma$-aditivity if there are two disjoint subsets with measures $\infty$ and $-\infty$?  You may try to rule out this kind of thing but this makes the theory pretty much useless.

Comment: Ah I meant finite signed measure. If necessarily, I restrict to continuous linear functional.

Comment: Any continuous linear functional on $C_0(X)$ in represented by a signed measure, assuming $X$ is a locally compact space.

Comment: Could you provide me with a reference containing such result?

Comment: First decompose your linear functional as a linear combination of self adjoint functionals, then apply the Jordan Decomposition (Murphy Thm 3.3.10), then use RMK.